# Free API or similar to get Next Earnings Date for stocks

Tags: api, stocks, financial

I am looking for an API or similar where I can get the next (upcoming) earnings date for a stock. I have googled for it and haven't found anything usable. I know of both the Yahoo and Google finance APIs, but none of them provide the next earnings date. Many sites, i.e.  www.finviz.com (look for "Earnings" here http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=c) have the next earnings date information, but no API to get it.

Does anyone know where I can fetch the next earnings date?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may have what you need, it's not free but it has a free trial which may be sufficient for your needs: http://www.zacksdata.com/zacks-data-api

*(Disclosure: This API is managed by my company)*

Comment: Hi Eugene. Didn't know about your companys feed and it does actually look like it can provide the info we need. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

again not free, but here is another one :

http://www.pracplay.com/products/starter/starter_reference#TOC-EventScreen

and the api :

http://www.pracplay.com/products/starter/starter_reference#TOC-Calendars-and-Other

(Disclosure: This API is managed by my company)